# How to compare all row varchar to datetime, and output difference in years, months, days

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

[image]

I have this database model in SQL Server 2008 R2.

**Request**

I want to show years, months, days of service in my company like the below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want exact numbers this is very tricky. How many months are 30 days? It depends on what month those days span.

But if we can use an approximation, and say that a month is always 30 days (so a year equals 360).

```
SELECT Id, dateStartworking,
( 
  CAST(DATEDIFF(d, dateStartworking, getDate()) / 30 / 12 AS varchar) + ' years ' +
  CAST(DATEDIFF(d, dateStartworking, getDate()) / 30 % 12 AS varchar) + ' months ' +
  CAST(DATEDIFF(d, dateStartworking, getDate()) % 30 AS varchar) + ' days'
) 
AS [Years of service] FROM MyData
```

SQL-server should work out that `dateStartWorking` is a valid date, but if it doesn't you might want to try and cast it too:

```
CAST(dateStartWorking AS DateTime)
```

Result:

```
Id  Datestartworking    Diff
-----------------------------------------------------------
1   20150203            0 years, 1 months, 28 days
2   20150305            0 years, 0 months, 28 days
3   20140115            1 years, 2 months, 22 days
```

I see that you must use some approximation in your calculations too, since the difference between 1996-07-08 and 2015-04-02 is reported as 19 years 2 months 24 days. With my above script this would be: 19 years 0 months 2 days.

If I'm not mistaken that means my example is more accurate, since the "actual" difference would be something like 18 years ~9 months.

**Edit, for better precision:**

For a bit more precision you can use `year = 365.242199 days` and `month = 30.4368499 days`:

```
SELECT Id, dateStartworking,
( 
   CAST(CAST(ROUND(DATEDIFF(d, dateStartworking, getDate()) / 365.242199, 0, 1) AS int) AS varchar) + ' years ' +
   CAST(CAST(ROUND(DATEDIFF(d, dateStartworking, getDate()) / 30.4368499, 0, 1) AS int) % 12 AS varchar) + ' months ' +
   CAST(CAST(ROUND(DATEDIFF(d, dateStartworking, getDate()) % 30.4368499, 0 ,1) AS int) AS varchar) + ' days'
) 
AS [Years of service] FROM MyData
```

This will report the above difference (1996-07-08) as `18 years 8 months 24 days`. Close enough!